# font-style: italic changing size of input on Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to fix an issue on my inputs, where I change the style of the font to italic whenever the input is dirty. This works fine on Firefox. However on Chrome, when I apply `font-style: italic;` to a text input with, for instance, `size="5"`, the input repaints itself with a different width.

You can check a basic example here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aeNoBV

Just remove the style of the input.

Is this a bug on Chrome, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `size` attribute on `input` causes input width calculation that depends on the character font on Chrome.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56502674/8598108).

I'd recommend to use another method for the input like `width` itself that regardless of the `font-style` will not be modified.

Comment: Thanks, It seems I'll have to play a bit with different widths so everything falls in place.